# Flyback 120-240VAC to 3.3VDC ripple and simulation

Tags: ac, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, ripple

I'm working on a project requiring a 3.3VDC and eventually a 12VDC. The input voltage could be either 120VAC or 240VAC 60Hz.

I've found and replicated the design [PMP10143](https://www.ti.com/tool/PMP10143) proposed by Texas Instrument with only the 3.3VDC output part for now. Here is the current schematic :

[image]

The current issue is the ripple that is pretty high :

[image]

Now wondering if there is something wrong with either the design transfer or the original design. Also, for test I tried to recreate a simulation, but can't find an opto coupler to recreate it.

Help about the ripple source and/or the circuit simulation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is a usual for that kind of supplies. To reduce fluctuation you may put LDO voltage regulator. Just make the bottom of fluctuation above the min input of LDO

Comment: @user263983 Well actually this design has test with less than 60mVpp into the test results and is recommanded for microcontroller. There is something wrong that makes me get 400mVpp.

Comment: I did reverse ingineering on some of those PS,  most have inductors in output.

Comment: The measurement above was made with what load?

Comment: @user263983 Yes sure I'll add another stage filter at the end, but still something wrong that I want to fix before this stage.

Comment: @vtolentino It was made with a load d'approx. 120mA.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie could you share your layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a long shot, but the high ripple voltage you are seeing is because of the electrolytic capacitor \$C_4\$ you picked. According to the its datasheet it has an \$ESR=160m\Omega @ 100kHz\$

[image: datasheet_1]

The capacitor used in the reference design is a tantalum one, with an equivalent \$ESR=18m\Omega @ 100kHz\$

[image: datasheet_2]

Although you are switching at a lower frequency (\$\approx 5kHz\$), if you were to linearly interpolate, you could roughly assume the following:

- When the MOSFET is turned off, the voltage at the secondary winding raises and begins to charge the output capacitor
- Since your current capacitor has a higher ESR, it will be charged a bit more slowly, by a factor of approx:
  $$factor\approx\dfrac{1-e^{-1}}{1-e^{-0.1}}=6.64$$
- It means that during this period the voltage at the secondary winding will take a bit more time to drop.

This can be roughly checked with a small simulation:

Basically this simulation shows a flyback converter with a fixed frequency regulation. Essentially the gate of the mosfet is turned off whenever the output voltage exceeds \$V_{out}=3.3V\$. The simulation is run for two different \$ESR\$ values, and as you can see the ripple voltage with the bigger \$ESR\$ is approximately 8 times higher.

[image: circuit]

In order to confirm this suspicion, you can either add more capacitors in parallel at output in order to reduce the equivalent \$ESR\$, or select a tantalum capacitor with very low \$ESR\$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll take a look into the ESR tomorrow and also look if I have some tantalum caps available or other with lower ESR at least, and in parallel as you suggest.